# Django DRF - how to deserialize an instance that requires a foreign key?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization, django-serializer

I have a Page model, and a Paragraph model that references its Page. I want to create both modules by deserializing a JSON representation like this:

```
{
    "page": {
        "number": 32,
        "book": "Moby Dick",
        "paragraphs": [
            {
                "label": "I am a Paragraph within the Page"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And here are my Paragraph and Page models:

```py
class Paragraph(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(
        Page,
        help_text="Every Paragraph must belong to a Page",
        related_name="paragraphs",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    label = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_paragraph'

class Page(models.Model):
    # This is not unique!
    number = models.IntegerField()
    # This is not unique!
    book = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # but "number" and "book" together are unique.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'my_page'
```

How can I deserialize that representation to instantiate my models?

I tried creating these serializers below:

```py
class ParagraphSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    page = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field="id",
        queryset=models.Page.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Paragraph
        fields = '__all__'


class PageSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    paragraphs = ParagraphSerializer(
        many=True,
    )

    # This method never gets called, because PageSerializer validation fails.
    def create(self, validated_data):
        paragraphs_data = validated_data.pop('paragraphs')
        page = models.Page.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for paragraph_data in paragraphs_data:
            # We'll need to find some way of adding a `page` field to this paragraph...
            paragraph_data['page'] = page.id
            serializer = ParagraphSerializer(data=paragraph_data)
            serializer.is_valid()
            serializer.save()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Page
        fields = '__all__'
```

But I'm getting errors because `SlugRelatedField` requires my `paragraph` JSON to reference it's Page:

```py
serializer = PageSerializer(data=page_json)
serializer.is_valid()
# is_valid() fails with the following message:
# [{'paragraphs': [{'page': [u'This field is required.']}]}, {}]
```

Should I try adding a `page` field to my `paragraphs` JSON, and if so, which `slug_field` should I use? Unfortunately, the only unique field on Page is `id`. But the compound key of `book` and `number` **is** unique.

Or is there a way to make `is_valid()` pass on my PageSerializer, so that we can specify the `page` field on the `paragraph` model in the `PageSerializer.create` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the `page` attribute from my `ParagraphSerializer`, and setting it manually in the `ParagraphSerializer.create` method.

This was possible by passing my Page model through the serializer's context object, like so:

```py
class ParagraphSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Paragraph
        exclude = 'page'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return models.Paragraph.objects.create(
            page=self.context.get("page"),
            **validated_data
        )

class PageSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    paragraphs = ParagraphSerializer(
        many=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Page
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        paragraphs_data = validated_data.pop('paragraphs')
        page = models.Page.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for paragraph_data in paragraphs_data:
            # We'll need to find some way of adding a `page` field to this paragraph...
            paragraph_data['page'] = page.id
            serializer = ParagraphSerializer(
                data=paragraph_data, 
                context={"page": page}
            )
            serializer.is_valid()
            serializer.save()
        return page
```

I didn't have to change my models, nor my JSON representation!

It all made sense when I came across this blog post, which was helpful in describing the possibilities of passing the `context` object through a serializers `create` method:
https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-rest-framework-send-extra-context-data-to-serializers/